# what user profile is used for user entring to a machine with "enter-pssession"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, powershell

in an AD environment, where a user is part of "Domain Administrator", now if that user logs in to a machine using remote powershell using "enter-pssession" will it create any user profile for the user, if so will there be any group policies applied on it?

Answer (score 1):

By default it will create a user profile in the remote machine while using the command "Enter-PSSession".

If you want to avoid this creation add the following to your command:

```
-SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)
```

As well the Group Policy Settings will take effect the User Preferences set for the corresponding user at the domain level.